# How to specify an entailment-regime in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdfs

There is a W3C standard on entailment regimes in SPARQL. However, it does not mention how an entailment regime should be specified in a SPARQL query. Nor does it give any examples. I haven't found a single example of the Web either... So how does one specify entailment regimes in a SPARQL query? Can it be done at all?

```
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.com/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?property
WHERE {
  ?property rdfs:subPropertyOf ex:someTopProperty .
}
```

I would like bindings for `?property` to be closed under transitivity (part of RDFS entailment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entailment regimes are an optional extension point of SPARQL so there is no requirement for a SPARQL engine to support entailment regimes.

Where entailment regimes are supported how these are enabled is an implementation specific detail and not specified/standardised anywhere.  Some engines may allow you to only specify a single entailment regime which is always on while others may allow you to change entailment regimes on a per-query basis.

Generally you should contact the vendor(s) of the SPARQL engines you are wanting to use to see what entailment regimes they support and how that support is configured and enabled.

### Edit

As for how you determine what entailment regime is used you can try and get the [SPARQL 1.1 service description](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) of an endpoint which may include properties such as `sd:defaultEntailmentRegime`

However that information (if an endpoint provides it) would typically only tell you about the configuration of the endpoint and not necessarily about possible configurations

Comment: Thanks for the info! I get that not every SPARQL endpoint can be forced to support every (or even a) entailment regime. But I would have expected that at least querying whether an endpoint supports entailment (an if so, what specific regimes) would have been standardized by now. A machine processor is not able to find this out.

Comment: @WouterBeek Updated my answer to point you to the [SPARQL 1.1 Service Description](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) specification which includes the ability to describe the entailment regime